# Nonlinear initial BVP

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I wonder if the following PDE can be solved by hand:
\begin{align*}
u_{t}=u_{xx}+e^u,
\end{align*}
where $x\in [-1,1]$, $t>0$, $u(\pm 1,t)=u(x,0)=0$. If not, when solving numerically, how to deal with the $e^u$ term? In matrix form, we have
$$
u_{t}=Tu+e^u,
$$
where
$$
T=\begin{bmatrix}
-2  & 1\\
1 & -2 & 1 \\
& 1 & -2 & 1\\
&& \ddots & \ddots & \ddots \\
&&&1 & -2 & 1 \\
&&&& 1 & -2 \end{bmatrix}
$$
We denote the approximation of $u(x_{n},t_{m})$ by $u^{m}_{n}$. The domain is set to be $[-1,1]$. Since the boundaries are known, we will only look at the interior points. Applying the trapezoidal rule, we get
$$
\frac {u^{m+1}-u^{m}}{\Delta t}=\frac {1}{2}\left[Tu^{m}+e^{u^{m}}+Tu^{m+1}+e^{u^{m+1}}\right],
$$
or
$$
\left[I-\frac {\Delta t}{2}T\right]u^{m+1}=\left[I+\frac {\Delta t}{2}T\right]u^{m}+\frac {\Delta t}{2}\left(e^{u^{m}}+e^{u^{m+1}}\right).
$$
I wonder how to deal with $\frac {\Delta t}{2}\left(e^{u^{m}}+e^{u^{m+1}}\right)$ on the right hand side. Is there any way to write $e^{u^{m+1}}$ in terms of $u^{m+1}$ so that I can move it over to the left hand side?

Comment: You can use an implici-explicit (IMEX) version of your method... If you don't leave the exponential explicit, you'll have to solve a nonlinear system (which is totally doable but probably not necessary)

Comment: Also, for small $u$, you may consider the approximation $e^{u^{m+1}}\approx 1 + u^{m+1}$. However, this may break the $O(\Delta x^2)$ convergence in space.

Comment: I wonder how to write $1+u^{m+1}$ as some matrix times $u^{m+1}$? I feel like this matrix should be somehow close to the identity matrix. (Not sure how to deal with the $1$) Okay, I think I get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the numerical solution, for each time step $t_i$, we have

$$
u_t(t_i,x) = u_{xx}(t_i, x) + e^{u(t_i,x)}.
$$

Approximating the time derivative on the LHS, and using finite differences on the RHS, we get:

$$
\frac{1}{\Delta t}(u_{i}(x_j)-u_{i-1}(x_j)) = \frac{1}{\Delta x^2}(u_i(x_{j+1})-2u_i(x_j)+u_i(x_{j-1})) + e^{u_i(x_j)}
$$

This corresponds to solving a nonlinear system at each time step, to determine $u_i(x)$ over the space grid $(x_j)$. If you want a linear system instead, you can make the exponential term explicit by substituting it by $e^{u_{i-1}(x_j)}$.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wonder can I use the trapezoidal method instead?

Comment: @Analyst_311419 Sure, the trapezoidal method is fine. I used an explicit method for the advance in time just to avoid describing the iterations within each time step.